# How to handle useState asynchronous in React hooks (in my case)

Tags: react-hooks

Here `products` state is `null` when I try to display the product. I know to handle this we can use useEffect again for displaying the product but still `product` state is null. Here is the part of the code that I tried to attempt.

```
function Product() {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:4000/products")
      .then((res) => setProducts(res.data));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
   console.log(products); // Here still products is null
    products.map((product) => (
      <tr key={product.id}>
        <td>{product.productName}</td>
        <td>{product.productDesc}</td>
        <td>{product.manufacturer}</td>
        <td>{product.price}</td>
        <td>{product.quantity}</td>
      </tr>
    ));
  }, [products]);

  return <></>;
}
```

If I remove `products.map` then it is showing as two values first one is `null` and the second is an `array of the object` (i.e my data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a typical example of `lifting the state up` to the higher-order component in React.js.
All states and API calls need to be written in your top-level-component.

```
import ProductItem from "./ProductItem";

function Product(){
  const [products, setProducts] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:4000/products")
      .then((res) => setProducts(res.data));
  }, []);

return(
     <table>
       <thead>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>Manufacturer</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Qunatity</th>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
          <ProductItem products={products} />
       </thead>
     </table>
 );
}
```

Here, the `products` state is passed as a prop to ProductItem. Now the ProductItem component will have the list of the product's item which can be accessed as a prop.

```
function ProductItem({products}) {

  useEffect(() => {
   console.log(products); // getting the list of the product in the developer console,
  }, [products]);

  return (
    <>
     {products.map((product) => (
      <tr key={product.id}>
        <td>{product.productName}</td>
        <td>{product.productDesc}</td>
        <td>{product.manufacturer}</td>
        <td>{product.price}</td>
        <td>{product.quantity}</td>
      </tr>
      ))}
   </>;
 );
}
export default ProductItem;
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now, nothing will ever be rendered as the return is empty (almost).

Try

```
function Product() {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:4000/products")
      .then((res) => setProducts(res.data));
  }, []);

 if (!products) {
    return null;
 }

 return products.map(product => (
    <tr key={product.id}>
        <td>{product.productName}</td>
        <td>{product.productDesc}</td>
        <td>{product.manufacturer}</td>
        <td>{product.price}</td>
        <td>{product.quantity}</td>
    </tr>
 ));
}
```

Comment: still `products` state is null.

Comment: Do make sure that you are getting something out of your endpoint, is res.data containing you what you expect?

Comment: i did `console.log(products)` in another useEffect only but the first time it is showing as null then the second time it is showing as array of object(ie. my data).

Comment: Try
axios
      .get("http://localhost:4000/products")
      .then((res) => {
           console.log(res);
           setProducts(res.data));
     });